# Strange networking issue in Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, dns, youtube

My problem is hard to explain. I can’t open some sites. For example some sites provided by Google. I can open the Google search engine, however I can’t open YouTube, the download page for Chrome (the browser). Another example is Microsoft, I can open the site however I can’t open `http://iso.esd.microsoft.com/` from where, I should be able to download the Windows 10 Insider Preview. I get “Server Not Found” error in Firefox and “Web page not found” on Chromium. I can see that the sites are up from the site [Down for Everyone Or Just Me](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/). Also I can open them from my Android device, and another laptop running Windows 8.1; the machine which has problem is Ubuntu.

What I’ve done so far: disabled `ufw` (uncomplicated firewall), changed the DNS servers provided by my ISP with the Google DNS servers(`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`).

Any idea what my problem could be.

`nslookup` for `iso.esd.microsoft.com` NOTE downforeveryoneorjustme.com said that the site is up.

```
 $ nslookup 
> set debug
> iso.esd.microsoft.com
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    iso.esd.microsoft.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
** server can't find iso.esd.microsoft.com: REFUSED
```

`nslookup` with different DNS

```
$ nslookup 
> server
Default server: 89.233.43.71
Address: 89.233.43.71#53
> iso.esd.microsoft.com/
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

When I changed my DNS server settings, this is what I did: I opened a terminal and I had type network-admin, the go to the DNS tab, I removed the default configuration (127.0.1.1) and added `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` after this I saw that I cannot connect to the sites and move the things back so now I’m using `127.0.1.1` again. I want to mention that I was able to connect to Youtube, listen some music then YouTube stopped again (probably only for me since my Android was working fine with it) and now it's up again.

The output from `dig`:

```
# dig @8.8.8.8 iso.esd.microsoft.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 iso.esd.microsoft.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56357
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 13, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 16

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;iso.esd.microsoft.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
iso.esd.microsoft.com.  2026    IN  CNAME   iso.esd.microsoft.com.nsatc.net.
iso.esd.microsoft.com.nsatc.net. 482 IN CNAME   main.esd.microsoft.com.nsatc.net.
main.esd.microsoft.com.nsatc.net. 482 IN CNAME  esd.microsoft.com.edgesuite.net.
esd.microsoft.com.edgesuite.net. 20386 IN CNAME a2047.ms.akamai.net.
a2047.ms.akamai.net.    19  IN  A   92.122.51.80
a2047.ms.akamai.net.    19  IN  A   92.122.51.74
a2047.ms.akamai.net.    19  IN  A   92.122.51.75
a2047.ms.akamai.net.    19  IN  A   92.122.51.73
a2047.ms.akamai.net.    19  IN  A   92.122.51.59
a2047.ms.akamai.net.    19  IN  A   92.122.51.67
a2047.ms.akamai.net.    19  IN  A   92.122.51.66
a2047.ms.akamai.net.    19  IN  A   92.122.51.81
a2047.ms.akamai.net.    19  IN  A   92.122.51.64

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
net.            172561  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172561  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172561  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172561  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172561  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172561  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172561  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172561  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172561  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172561  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172561  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172561  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172561  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  A   192.5.6.30
a.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  AAAA    2001:503:a83e::2:30
b.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  A   192.33.14.30
b.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  AAAA    2001:503:231d::2:30
c.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  A   192.26.92.30
d.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  A   192.31.80.30
e.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  A   192.12.94.30
f.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  A   192.35.51.30
g.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  A   192.42.93.30
h.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  A   192.54.112.30
i.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  A   192.43.172.30
j.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  A   192.48.79.30
k.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  A   192.52.178.30
l.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  A   192.41.162.30
m.gtld-servers.net. 172561  IN  A   192.55.83.30

;; Query time: 60 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sun May 10 17:33:02 EEST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 815
```

`ping` to `microsoft.com`:

```
  # ping microsoft.com
    PING microsoft.com (134.170.185.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
    --- microsoft.com ping statistics ---
    6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5040ms
```

NOTE: I was able to connect to microsoft.com via firefox.

`ping` to `google.com`:

```
# ping google.com
PING google.com (178.132.81.53) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 178.132.81.53: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=17.4 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.53: icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=16.5 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.53: icmp_seq=3 ttl=61 time=2.62 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.53: icmp_seq=4 ttl=61 time=2.86 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.53: icmp_seq=5 ttl=61 time=15.9 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.53: icmp_seq=6 ttl=61 time=2.60 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.53: icmp_seq=7 ttl=61 time=2.69 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.53: icmp_seq=8 ttl=61 time=2.67 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.53: icmp_seq=9 ttl=61 time=2.75 ms
64 bytes from 178.132.81.53: icmp_seq=10 ttl=61 time=602 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9013ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.606/66.902/602.814/178.746 ms
```

`traceroute` to `google.com`:

```
# traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (178.132.81.57), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  3.228 ms  3.156 ms  3.104 ms
 2  ip-160-129.powernet.bg (91.148.160.129)  3.919 ms  8.229 ms  8.220 ms
 3  178.132.84.98 (178.132.84.98)  8.196 ms  8.185 ms  8.164 ms
 4  TH-BG2.telehouse.bg (178.132.80.1)  8.651 ms  8.529 ms  8.530 ms
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

`traceroute` to `microsoft.com`:

```
# traceroute microsoft.com
traceroute to microsoft.com (134.170.185.46), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  8.400 ms  162.040 ms  161.921 ms
 2  ip-160-129.powernet.bg (91.148.160.129)  162.067 ms  161.853 ms  161.732 ms
 3  * * *
 4  TH-R03.telehouse.bg (178.132.83.49)  161.028 ms  160.906 ms  160.808 ms
 5  msft-decix-01-fra.ntwk.msn.net (80.81.194.52)  163.506 ms  163.393 ms  163.480 ms
 6  ae6-0.pra-96cbe-1a.ntwk.msn.net (191.234.82.51)  163.395 ms ae12-0.fra-96cbe-1b.ntwk.msn.net (191.234.84.121)  32.869 ms ae6-0.pra-96cbe-1a.ntwk.msn.net (191.234.82.51)  44.238 ms
 7  ae14-0.lon04-96cbe-1b.ntwk.msn.net (191.234.84.118)  49.290 ms  51.251 ms ae6-0.ams-96c-1b.ntwk.msn.net (207.46.42.52)  41.917 ms
 8  ae11-0.amb-96cbe-1b.ntwk.msn.net (191.234.81.179)  42.028 ms * *
 9  ae4-0.lts-96cbe-1a.ntwk.msn.net (204.152.141.123)  47.703 ms  47.681 ms ae0-0.nyc-96cbe-1b.ntwk.msn.net (207.46.38.113)  118.306 ms
10  ae12-0.was02-96cbe-1c.ntwk.msn.net (191.234.84.144)  123.888 ms  123.974 ms ae4-0.lon04-96cbe-1a.ntwk.msn.net (191.234.81.154)  49.392 ms
11  ae12-0.lon04-96cbe-1b.ntwk.msn.net (207.46.44.163)  46.454 ms 191.234.85.32 (191.234.85.32)  121.871 ms  121.938 ms
12  * * *
13  * ae0-0.nyc-96cbe-1b.ntwk.msn.net (207.46.38.113)  115.177 ms  113.239 ms
14  ae12-0.was02-96cbe-1c.ntwk.msn.net (191.234.84.144)  119.999 ms * *
15  191.234.85.32 (191.234.85.32)  120.358 ms *  121.587 ms
16  * ae3-0.den01-96cbe-1a.ntwk.msn.net (191.234.80.193)  163.156 ms  162.673 ms
17  * * ae9-0.cys01-96cbe-1a.ntwk.msn.net (191.234.84.176)  169.562 ms
18  * * *
19  * ae9-0.co2-96c-1a.ntwk.msn.net (191.234.82.236)  188.094 ms  190.180 ms
20  * * *
21  ae9-0.cys01-96cbe-1a.ntwk.msn.net (191.234.84.176)  164.271 ms * *
22  * * *
23  * * ae10-0.co2-96c-1b.ntwk.msn.net (191.234.82.239)  185.713 ms
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

`traceroute` to `youtube.com`:

```
$ traceroute youtube.com
traceroute to youtube.com (178.132.81.46), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  1.822 ms  2.075 ms  2.391 ms
 2  ip-160-129.powernet.bg (91.148.160.129)  7.068 ms  6.949 ms  6.841 ms
 3  178.132.84.98 (178.132.84.98)  6.988 ms  7.146 ms  7.052 ms
 4  TH-BG2.telehouse.bg (178.132.80.1)  7.163 ms  7.071 ms  8.168 ms
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

`traceroute` to `iso.esd.microsoft.com`:

```
# traceroute iso.esd.microsoft.com
iso.esd.microsoft.com: Name or service not known
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `iso.esd.microsoft.com' on position 1 (argc 1)
```

I’ve flushed `iptables`, but all policies were set to ACCEPT by default.

Also I was able to connect to YouTube and `iso.esd.microsoft.com` (while they weren't working for me) via proxy (`kproxy.com`).

Comment: Let's see what your system is getting. On Windows, open a command line window, then run `nslookup` without parameters, then inside it `set debug` followed by `iso.esd.microsoft.com` (or any other host name you're having trouble with on that system). Copy the full output from that into your question by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: The system is running Linux, I have another laptop with Windows are you sure you want the result from Windows?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question and thought the problematic system was running Windows. You should be able to do exactly the same thing on Linux. The idea is to see where name resolution fails, and nslookup in debug mode provides an easy way to get some information about that. It might not tell us everything we'll need in order to answer the question, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: Well, this is better. One more thing: please clarify exactly where you changed your DNS server settings.

Comment: I opened a terminal and I had type network-admin, the go to the DNS tab, I removed the default configuration(127.0.1.1) and added 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 after this I saw that I cannot connect to the sites and move the things back so now I'm using 127.0.1.1 again. 
I want to mention that I was able to connect to Youtube, listen some music then Youtube stopped again(probably only for me since my Android was working fine with it) and now it's up again.

Comment: I suspect a problem with the ISP itself. Am I correct that the host failed to resolve correctly from both the Linux host _and_ the Windows host (which responded with `REFUSED` to the request)?  See ǝɲǝɲbρɯͽ's answer re dig... and my comment there.

Comment: I don't have any problem with Windows or Android, the problem doesn't seems to be with my ISP, the issue is on Linux only.

Comment: Your second nslookup "with different dns" + result NXDOMAIN...it's fine to include the second test, but don't use the protocol (http://) or path (/); that's a syntax error / DNS doesn't know what to do with that stuff.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I had edited the post

Answer (score 1):

You say you changed your DNS to Google servers, but your server is returning `127.0.1.1` as your DNS server.

[This page on the official Ubuntu site](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop) might point us in the direction of understanding; specifically in the “Networking” section:

> In order to improve compatibility with other local nameserver
>   packages, NetworkManager now assigns IP address `127.0.1.1` to the
>   local nameserver process that it controls instead of `127.0.0.1`. If
>   the system's `/etc/resolv.conf` is absent or is a static file instead
>   of the symbolic link to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` installed by
>   default then this static file will have to be updated by the
>   administrator in order to continue using the NetworkManager-controlled
>   nameserver.

Meanwhile, in nslookup set your DNS server as:

```
server=8.8.8.8
```

And try again.

Or better yet, set it to an uncensored DNS—such as the DNS at [www.censurfridns.dk](http://www.censurfridns.dk) like this:

```
server=89.233.43.71
```

Comment: Yes, I changed the server to the google DNS, but after I saw that it doesn't work I changed back to the one provided by my ISP.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a weird network issue¹ but… [don’t use nslookup](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/nslookup.html). The essential reasons [are](http://veggiechinese.net./nslookup_sucks.txt) that it uses different lookup paths with less troubleshooting information and the tool is implemented [inconsistently](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/nslookup-host-dig-not-resolving-entries-in-etc-hosts-326300/). Alternatives include `dig` and `host`.

Skip the local resolver (127.0.0.1) and confirm that DNS for those *should* work on the system with either line:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 iso.esd.microsoft.com
$ host iso.esd.microsoft.com 8.8.8.8
```

In `dig` responses, a message size > 512 would cause a switch from UDP to TCP but I tried a few and they’re all below that:

```
www.microsoft.com
  ...response...
  ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 226

iso.esd.microsoft.com    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 352
www.youtube.com           ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 243
```

Ubuntu apparently changed to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/resolv.conf` for consistency [some time ago](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-p-dns-resolving). [This article](https://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/) discusses it, using `resolvconf` to guarantee `resolv.conf` changes aren’t lost, and covers `dnsmasq` (the local resolver). Summarizing, you can troubleshoot:

- Use nm-tool (Network Manager tool) and confirm the DNS: lines are as expected.
- Check if dnsmasq is running. If not, start it.
- If running, check `/run/nm-dns-dnsmasq.conf` for its resolvers.
- If dnsmasq isn't wanted, comment `dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and then `sudo restart network-manager`.
- Additionally use `resolvconf` and its hook files (`base`, `head`, `original` and `tail`) in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/` to configure DNS.

If `iptables` might be running, you can check that it’s not interfering:

```
$ sudo iptables -Z                      # Zero all counters
$ nslookup iso.esd.microsoft.com   # assuming it fails...
$ sudo iptables -L -v                   # ...are any REJECT/DROP counters > 0?
```

If it is and you don’t care about `iptables` (since you’re using another firewall) you can flush all rules or modify/delete the offending rules individually.

¹ I thought about network edge cases a while but decided to pull back closer to Ubuntu’s DNS; I’m on another distro so hopefully this isn’t too far off.

Comment: +1'd for dig @xxxx syntax.  To the OP: can you even ping the Google or MS DNS servers? Some of your responses indicate that maybe those are being filters. If the pings hang, try `traceroute -n` on linux or `tracert -d` on win. It might be 'tracepath' on linux now.